# Is it possible to replicate a Tesla valve in large scale?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, airflow, valves

Supposedly a [Tesla valve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_valve) will impede fluid or air flow in one direction whilst allowing flow to move freely through the valve entering from the opposite direction, without using any moving parts. Also the alleged effectiveness of the valve is based on its length, with a longer configuration being more efficient. 
Does anyone know if such a valve is scalable or does the properties of the valve diminish with greater size?

Comment: I like this question because I wondered the same thing, thinking about flood control systems where basins fill faster than they drain.

Answer (score 3):

This device works on momentum effects.

If the fluid had no momentum, it could just follow the channels wherever they go, and the resistance would be the same in both directions.  In the context of the fluid, the is what happens when the viscocity is high and the speed low relative to the size of the channels.

In short, this only works over a range of Reynolds numbers.  For example, if the channels were large, the fluid was molasses, and the speeds slow, you wouldn't see much difference in pressure between directions.